# How to display an image over the exact center of a table?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` and I wish to display an `<img>` over the `<table>` in the exact center.

How would I do that?

Comment: Are the dimensions of the table fixed?

Comment: Or, are the dimensions of the image fixed?

Comment: Pardon me for suggesting the obvious, but could you just create a cell in the center of the table that's exactly large enough to contain the image? Or are you planning on doing some trickery with z-orders and visibility rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimensions of the image are fixed (say, width 200 height 300), then something like this should work:

HTML:

```
<div id="table-and-image-container">
    <table id="the-table">...</table>
    <img src="..." id="the-image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#table-and-image-container
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#the-table
{
    z-index: 1;
}
#the-image
{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px; /* = 200px width of image / 2 */
    margin-top: -150px; /* = 300px height of image / 2 */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The containing `#table-and-image-container` will be the size of the table, since `position: absolute` will take `#the-image` out of the sizing algorithm and `display: inline-block` will reduce the width to the width of the table instead of 100% of the container. Then you use standard `top`/`left`/`margin` tricks to position the image in the center, and use `z-index` to make sure it goes on top.

Comment: Thanks Domenic, but this did not work.  The image appears in the vertical center of the table, but on the horizontal center of the page (not the table).  Have a look here:  http://jsfiddle.net/wxuwt/  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @NeedExpertHelp: To `#table-and-image-container`, add `float: left` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @NeedExpertHelp: indeed, `display: inline-block` was the way to go; editing my answer to reflect that. http://jsfiddle.net/wxuwt/4/

Comment: Thanks guys.  I can confirm that both `float: left` and `display: inline-block` make it work.  Why is that?

Comment: I addressed that in my edit :). `display: block` elements take up 100% of the parent container width by default (but can be overridden by setting the `width` and `height` attributes). `display: inline-block` only expands to the width of its children. As for `float: left`, I'm not entirely sure, because I hate `float` with a passion and wish people would stop abusing it, haha.